# read all files in directory ksh

Tags: ksh

I want to read all files one by one from the `/home/ram/files/*.txt`
and I want to remove the file If the file has less than or equal to 7 lines.

I am using `ksh` script

The follwoing code not working for me! pls help

```
for file in /home/ram/files/*.txt
do
 no_of_lines=$(wc -l "$file")
 if [[ $no_of_lines -le 7 ]];
  then
  rm "$file"
 fi
done
```

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 2):

`wc` command gives count and the filename as well.

Change it to:

```
no_of_lines=$(wc -l < "$file")
```

Comment: @user1990571 :If it is working, please accept the answer. If more than one answer helps you, accept the one that best matches the solution...